# postgresql subscription not working for schemas other than public

Tags: postgresql, schema, replication, logical-replication

I'm trying to create a logical replication with two local postgresql servers (node1: port 5434, node2: port 5435).

I could successfully create publication and subscription on node1 and node2 for a table in public schema.

Node1:

```
CREATE PUBLICATION my_pub FOR TABLE t1;
GRANT SELECT ON t1 TO repuser;
```

Node2:

```
CREATE SUBSCRIPTION my_sub CONNECTION 'host=localhost port=5434 dbname=pub user=repuser password=password' PUBLICATION my_pub;
```

Node2 public.t1 replicates all data in node1 public.t1.

However, my problem is when I create publication and subscription with same code but in different schema, node2 fail to replicate.

Below is output of some pg_catalog query :

Node1:

```
pub=# select * from pg_catalog.pg_publication_tables;
 pubname  | schemaname | tablename
----------+------------+-----------
 my_pub   | public     | t1
 cdl_test | cdl        | t1
 pub_test | test       | t1
```

Node2:

```
sub=# \dRs
              List of subscriptions
     Name     |  Owner   | Enabled | Publication
--------------+----------+---------+-------------
 cdl_sub_test | postgres | t       | {cdl_test}
 my_sub       | postgres | t       | {my_pub}
 sub_test     | postgres | t       | {pub_test}

sub=# select * from pg_catalog.pg_replication_origin;
 roident |  roname
---------+----------
       2 | pg_18460
       1 | pg_18461
       3 | pg_18466

sub=# select * from pg_catalog.pg_subscription_rel ;
 srsubid | srrelid | srsubstate |  srsublsn
---------+---------+------------+------------
   18461 |   16386 | r          | 0/3811C810
   18466 |   18463 | d          |
   18460 |   18456 | d          |
```

As it is shown in `select * from pg_catalog.pg_subscription_rel`, two subscription for test and cdl schema are in `d(data is being copied)` state.

Any recommendation on how to go about this problem or diagnose why the problem occurs?

As jjanes has suggested, a snippet of the log file is shown below:

```
2022-01-17 16:05:25.165 PST [622] WARNING:  out of logical replication worker slots
2022-01-17 16:05:25.165 PST [622] HINT:  You might need to increase max_logical_replication_workers.
2022-01-17 16:05:25.168 PST [970] LOG:  logical replication table synchronization worker for subscription "cdl_sub_test", table "t1" has started
2022-01-17 16:05:25.245 PST [970] ERROR:  could not start initial contents copy for table "cdl.t1": ERROR:  permission denied for schema cdl
2022-01-17 16:05:25.247 PST [471] LOG:  background worker "logical replication worker" (PID 970) exited with exit code 12022-01-17 16:05:25.797 PST [488] postgres@sub LOG:  statement: /*pga4dash*/
```

It seems like the subscriber doesn't have permission to read cdl schema in publisher even after I gave permission for `SELECT ON cdl.t1 TO repuser;`.

Comment: Look in the log files on the subscriber

Comment: Here is output of the log file : `2022-01-17 15:54:34.877 PST [622] WARNING:  out of logical replication worker slots
2022-01-17 15:54:34.877 PST [622] HINT:  You might need to increase max_logical_replication_workers.
2022-01-17 15:54:34.879 PST [647] LOG:  logical replication table synchronization worker for subscription "cdl_sub_test", table "t1" has started
2022-01-17 15:54:34.953 PST [647] ERROR:  could not start initial contents copy for table "cdl.t1": ERROR:  permission denied for schema cdl`

Comment: I don't understand why subscriber doesn't have permission for that schema. I did use `GRANT SELECT ON cdl.t1 TO repuser;` for that table...

Comment: table grants and schema grants are separate.  Being able to select on the table doesn't help if you can't find the table to start with because you can't see into the schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give the user `repuser` permission to read the table that should be replicated. That also requires `USAGE` permission on the schema that contains the table.

Comment: I did give permission to read the table using `GRANT SELECT on schema.table TO repuser;` Is there any other thing I need to do?

Comment: You didn't grant the required permissions on the schema.

Comment: Thank you Laurenz. `GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA schema TO repuser;` worked.